# Episerver - Cannot set Changed state to false after updating the Forum Topic

Tags: episerver, episerver-relate+

I have tried to update the forum topic as below,

```cs
EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic topic = GetTopic();
EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic topicClone = topic.CreateWritableClone() as EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic;

UpdateForumTopic(topicClone);// Edit the forum topic (e.g. change body text etc.) 

topicClone.Changed = topic.Changed; // This could not be done as there is no setter
EPiServer.Community.Forum.ForumHandler.Instance.UpdateTopic(topicClone); // Updating the forum topic will set the Changed state to true
```

However, I need to preserve the `Changed` state as it is even after updating the topic. Is there a way to do that?

*Additional info on my setup:

EPiServer.Community -  version=9.0.0

EPiServer.CommonFramework - version=9.0.1*

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ResetModified() method before saving your topicClone. ref https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7.5/602FB741

Comment: `EPiServer.Community.Forum.Topic` does not contain a definition for `ResetModified()`